# AJAX accessing untrusted HTTPS fails without 'do you want to proceed' prompt

Tags: jquery, ajax, security, ssl, https

I was pulling my hair over this until I browsed manually to the HTTPS server and saw the prompt

```
The site's security certificate is not trusted!
Proceed anyway / Back to safety
```

Apparently when AJAX was trying to access this page and it ran into this prompt and it would just automatically decide the connection should be rejected. Is there a way to propagate a prompt to the client? Or have AJAX choose 'proceed anyway' and ignore the warning?

P.S. I have access to the .crt's as well, but I've tried importing them into chrome's certificate stores and despite saying 'import successful' they never show up in the store...

Comment: considering that ajax is a background http request (e.g. "headless"), exactly how/where should that popup occur? it'd be confusing to the user since it's coming from an action they did not directly invoke themselves, and in the case of a jsonp request or similar, would be even more confusion because they're on site XYZ and getting an ssl error popup for site PQR

Comment: @Marc - You made me smile. You gotta love the browser security model and same origin busting. What little security that was present was disassembled to the point the a lucid error message cannot be presented. Sigh...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, it is a bad idea to access a https site with a bad certificate which results in a warning and expect the user to just accept the bad certificate. But, if this only for testing you need to direct the user first to page on the https server directly (without Ajax, iframe etc), and once the user accepted the certificate you can can continue with the ajax requests to the same host.

Comment: I can't seem to figure out how to give a key to the client though to make it a 'good' certificate.

Comment: @user997739: you have to get a certificate from a CA which is trusted by the browser. There are lots of resources out there on how to do it. If the CA is not trusted or does not match the hostname you will of course get the warnings which show this problem.

Comment: "It is a bad idea ... which results in a warning and expect the user to just accept the bad certificate" - Self-signed certificates elicit the same warning, and there's nothing wrong with them. [RFC 7250](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7250.txt) (and others) have provisions for them, but it means the CA/Browser cartel must be broken up.

Comment: @user997739 - the last time I checked, you *could not* do things like that. The details are purposefully hidden from you. Its why browsers are relegated to low value data. Their security model and some component designs *cannot* handle high value data.

Comment: @jww: SSL needs an identification of the peer, otherwise man-in-the-middle attacks would be possible. Self-signed certificates only allow such identification if each client verifies the fingerprint of the certificate over an independent communication channel and repeats this verification from time to time to make sure that the certificate was not compromised (self-signed can't be revoked the usual way). Of course this does not scale and thus self-signed certs  are only usable in a small and controlled environment (like for accessing home router) but not in the wide internet.

Comment: @jww: as for the use-case of RFC7250: "...in smaller deployments where the self-signed certificates are distributed to all involved protocol endpoints out-of-band..."

Comment: @Steffen - not just small deployments.... An organization with a trusted distribution channel does not need a cartel member to OK its app. And DANE/DNSSEC based deployments are general purpose and do not need the cartel (and it scales just fine).

Comment: @jww: With DNSSec you just have another set of trusted CAs: the  trusted root zones. Otherwise you would not be able to verify the signature of the DNS records. And, as long DNSSec is not widely used DANE will not work, because it depends on a trustable DNS (e.g. DNSSec) to distribute the certificates. Apart from that, larger organizations usually don't distribute self-signed certificates but have instead their own PKI and distribute only the necessary CA, because this scales much better.

Comment: "... as long DNSSec is not widely used DANE will not work, because it depends on a trustable DNS (e.g. DNSSec) to distribute the certificates" - Even free operators, like OpenSRS, offer DNSSEC. And Posfix is already using DANE for mail (see [Postfix README](http://www.postfix.org/TLS_README.html)). Thirteen root DNS KSKs is much better than hundred/thousands of CAs and SubCAs in the browser model. At least there's a 1:1 on the `{server, key}` pair.

Comment: @jww: I agree that if DNSSec would be widely used and would also be supported by current OS and routers, then we could use DANE instead of the current broken public PKI with 100s of CAs. Unfortunately it is still a long way to go, so currently DANE records are nice, but not sufficient. But, I don't think that the major problem is a "CA/Browser cartel", but instead it is just not that easy, fast and cheap to get DNSSec supported by all domains, routers, OS etc.